# (python) usual ValueError in parsing a date using datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I have read all other questions and checked thoroughly my script, but the error persists.

my test.txt file contains:

```
89.02 , 22/12/2016 
90.63 , 02/01/2017
```

where the order of the date is: day/month/year, and this is my script:

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
from matplotlib.dates import datestr2num
datefunc = lambda x: datestr2num(datetime.strptime(x, '%d/%m/%Y'))
values, date = np.loadtxt('test.txt', delimiter=',', unpack=True, converters = {1 : datefunc})
```

and I get the

```
ValueError: time data ' 22/12/2016 ' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y'
```

Does someone see a mistake in there? Thank you, that will be very appreciated

Comment: The error message shows that there are spaces around the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bcecause you have spaces around your string `x`

You can either use `strip()`:

```
>>> datetime.strptime(x.strip(), '%d/%m/%Y')
datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 22, 0, 0)
```

Or add spaces to format param:

```
>>> datetime.strptime(x, ' %d/%m/%Y ')
datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 22, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. In both cases I get `TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not iterable` and if I combine them I get back the old `ValueError`

Comment: so I tried removing `datestr2num` from the `lambda` function, but then numpy gives a `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number`, which I don't understand because I'm telling it to convert it to a date with the `converters` kwarg, right?

Comment: Please make sure you did not override any builtin functions and modules!

Comment: I solved it. `datestr2num` was not the correct method to call. The right one is `date2num`, always of the `matplotlib.dates` class. clearly, stripping the string was necessary too, so thanks a lot @ettanany and @mgilson

Answer (score 0):

The date data has extra space around it.  Try stripping the date string before passing it to `strptime`:

```
datefunc = lambda x: datestr2num(datetime.strptime(x.strip(), '%d/%m/%Y'))
```